# Cacher image button android

Tags: java, android, android-button

I have image button in item of recycle view..
I have to delete this image view everytime when some condition are not satisfied in my code Java.
How can i delete image button from java and not from xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These work fine for me.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseAdadper.BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Boolean isNeedToHide = true;
    ImageButton view = ....;
    if(isNeedToHide){
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    ....        
     
}
```